# Indexing variables with iterators

Tags: python, sage

I want to generate a FreeAlgebra with many generators, given in the list X.

```
X=[var('X_%d%d' %(i,j)) for i in range(1,10) for j in range(i+1,10)]
F = FreeAlgebra(QQ, X)
F.inject_variables()
```

How can I index the variables with iterators, for ex. something like write a dictionary of relations in F

```
X_ij * X_jk : X_jk * X_ij + X_ik, for i in range(1,10) for j in range(i+1,10) for k in range(j+1,10) ?
```

Then i need

```
A = F.g_algebra(D)
```

It works if I write each relation separately, X_12 * X_23 : X_23 * X_12 + X_13, but i would like it to work for any number of variables.

I tried with

```
X[i]*X[j] : X[j]*X[i] + X[some formula],
```

but it seems that the list X does not know that its elements are from the algebra F (nor A).

This is probably a very basic question - I am fresh newbie in Sage.
Thanks for help.

Comment: That's correct, `X` still will consider its elements to be symbolic elements.    You might get a result with `[F(x) for x in X]` - I don't know how the coercion would work nor how the `FreeAlgebra` syntax with colon works, but anyway it's worth a shot.

Comment: It's the same as `X[i]`. For example, `[x*X_12 for x in X]` gives me: `TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '*': 'Symbolic Ring' and
'Noncommutative Multivariate Polynomial Ring in...`

Comment: I think you'll have to coerce ALL the things into `F`.  I have time to give a full answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `X` is still a list of symbolic variables (with side effect of injection, which you then overrode by injecting free algebra variables).  Here is one with fewer side effects, but still same point.

```
X = ['X_%d%d' %(i,j)  for i in range(1,10) for j in range(i+1,10)]
F = FreeAlgebra(QQ, X)
F.inject_variables()
```

But if you then coerce each of them to `F` you are fine - [see this example](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFzbEKwjAUheFd8B3uEppoEOPu0CV7t0ApIbXXckOJ5Rqkvr1pFsfzDed3cIe-cV5MYmpASNJRATxfDASUgEOaURptrqpi_COdKw_Hgy0flhHbZcaRg-w6DU4Vv1CK-Mj-E5jCuOBbFl2ZUob8XVE6b25Feis3ddpHbWx7ww0_GjEsaA==&lang=sage):

```
X = ['X_%d%d' %(i,j)  for i in range(1,10) for j in range(i+1,10)]
F = FreeAlgebra(QQ, X)
F.inject_variables()
print type(X_12)
[F(x)*X_12 for x in X]
```

which will give you what you want.  Note how `X_12` is indeed an element of `F`, but the `x in X` are not.

Comment: Yes, this works for F. Thanks! I also need it in A = F.g_algebra(D), but it is said in [references](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/algebras/sage/algebras/free_algebra.html) that for g_algebra "Coercion doesn’t work yet". Do you know some other way to make this work in g_algebra without coercion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not as familiar with that.